# Turn string from query into integer for another query

Tags: php, mysqli, integer

Basically, I have a query that gets a number from a database, I then need to take the number, turn it into an integer so I can add 1 to it, then query it again to update the database.

Basically, I want it so every time someone clicks it updates the database number to be the same number + 1.

Code:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$curr = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT `likes` FROM savage WHERE `id` = '$id'");
$curr2 = intval($curr) + 1;
mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE savage SET `likes`='$curr2' WHERE `id`='$id'");
```

I attempted to use intval? I was just making an attempt.

Comment: Why is the number stored as a string in the database?  Also, what does this code produce; i.e. what's the problem?

Comment: Actually, having looked at it just now, the docs for mysqli here aren't as useful as they should be. Its a good reason to switch to PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php Which also works for more database types than just MySQL anyway.

Comment: The value is being stored as an integer in the database, but when I just do $curr + 1 it will update the number to "2" in the database when the number was 0 originally. Then, if you try to do the same thing when the number is "2" it won't update at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, it would be better to do:

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE savage SET `likes`=`likes`+1 WHERE `id`='$id'");
```

If you read the value in PHP, then add one, then save, you could be getting the data out of sync.

Imagine two people hit this page at once. If they truly came in order, you would get:

> Person A: The db reads as 1. You add 1 and save.  Value will now be 2.
>
> Person B: The db reads as 2. You add 1 and save.  Value will now be 3.

But it might happen that each one reads the db at about the same time:

> Person A: The db reads as 1. You add 1 and save.  Value will now be 2.
>
> Person B: The db reads as 1. You add 1 and save.  Value will now be 2.

In other words, you could be incrementing a stale value and saving. If you do it all in one SQL statement you don't get this problem.